# How to dismiss a Privacy Consent overlay in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


op_path: str = r"D:\Coding\Python\Projekte\Minecraft Updater\stuff\chromedriver.exe"

driver=webdriver.Chrome(op_path)

driver.get('https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods')



driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Akeptieren"]').click()
```

I'm trying to scrape https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods, however the page first asks me to consent to some sort of cookie privacy thing. All the locators I've tried for the "Accept" button don't seem to work though. I make sure the overlay has already popped up before trying to search for the button, but even so it throws up a "no such element" error.

Here's the HTML section of the accept button:

```
<button tabindex="0" title="Akzeptieren" aria-label="Akzeptieren" class="message-component message-button no-children buttons-row" path="[0,3,1]" style="padding: 10px 18px; margin: 10px; border-width: 1px; border-color: rgb(37, 53, 81); border-radius: 0px; border-style: solid; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 700; color: rgb(37, 53, 81); font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; width: auto; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Akzeptieren</button>
```

I'm new to HTML and selenium so I'm having a really hard time understanding how to click this damn button!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your accept button is in an iframe.

In Selenium you need to switch to that frame to access the content then switch back when done.
To allow for sync issues, it's good to use a webdriver wait. More info on Selenium's waits [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

This works for me

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.get('https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods')

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[contains(@id,'sp_message_iframe')]")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Akeptieren']"))).click()
driver.switch_to_default_content()

##continue with your script
```

the selenium docs recommend against mixing implicit and explicit waits.
If you prefer to stick the the implicit approach, this also work:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.get('https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@id,'sp_message_iframe')]")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Akeptieren']").click()
driver.switch_to_default_content()

##continue with your script
```